# FAILED: #-2147467259 System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): Access denied

Tags: macos, mono, socketexception

I am trying to get mono up and running on my MacBook Pro.

After successfully installing Mono I am running through the tests as recommended at [Getting Started](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/mono-basics/)

Everything was going great until I got to the test that involves running

`mono tlstest.exe https://www.nuget.org`

to test the https connectivity of the mono installation.

When I do this, I get the following error :

```
FAILED: #-2147467259
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): Access denied
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP)
  [0x000b6] in <5afdc70d980c4033b3878286f754d091>:0
  at TlsTest.GetStreamPage (System.String url) [0x00057] in 
  <7ad9caa5280c42fa9e47b5cc3d9b1e0e>:0
  at TlsTest.Main (System.String[] args) [0x002aa] in 
  <7ad9caa5280c42fa9e47b5cc3d9b1e0e>:0
```

I don't even know where to begin with troubleshooting.

I have a MacBook Pro running MacOS 10.12.6

Mono Version is as follows:

```
Mono JIT compiler version 5.0.1.1 (2017-02/5077205 Thu May 18 16:11:37 EDT 2017)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           normal
    SIGSEGV:       altstack
    Notification:  kqueue
    Architecture:  x86
    Disabled:      none
    Misc:          softdebug 
    LLVM:          yes(3.6.0svn-mono-master/8b1520c)
    GC:            sgen (concurrent by default)
```

Any help, guidance, or even some suggestions on where to start with troubleshooting this error would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems like a permissions issue, try with `sudo`, (`sudo mono tlstest.exe https://www.nuget.org`) and see if you get a `CERT_E_CHAINING` error instead of the access denied exception.

Comment: I get the same error, even when I do that.

MYMAC1:MonoTestApps admin$ sudo mono tlstest.exe [https://www.nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org)
Password:

FAILED: #-2147467259
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): Access denied
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP) [0x000b6] in <5afdc70d980c4033b3878286f754d091>:0 
  at TlsTest.GetStreamPage (System.String url) [0x00057] in <7ad9caa5280c42fa9e47b5cc3d9b1e0e>:0 
  at TlsTest.Main (System.String[] args) [0x002aa] in <7ad9caa5280c42fa9e47b5cc3d9b1e0e>:0

Comment: Do you have `LittleSnitch` (or some other macOS Firewall) denying the connections?

Comment: No. But I found that MacOS by default uses some kind of rootless security. I disabled that (Apple advises against this) using the procedure here https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-turn-off-the-rootless-in-OS-X-El-Capitan-10-11

Comment: Now when I run the same command I get this MonoTestApps admin$ mono tlstest.exe https://www.nuget.org

https://www.nuget.org
[X509Certificate: *.nuget.org]
 Valid From:  1/25/2017 3:34:28 PM
 Valid Until: 3/25/2018 4:34:28 PM

Error #-2146762486: CERT_E_CHAINING 0x800B010A
MYMAC1:MonoTestApps admin$

Comment: So now after disabling that MacOS rootless security, I get CERT_E_CHAINING error. Still a far cry from the expected results. Any help solving this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `CERT_E_CHAINING` error is expected... but you should ***not*** have to disable system integrity protection to run network connections via Mono....

Comment: Any ideas how to fix this? What would cause me to have to disable SIP to run network connections via mono?